# Python: add content to file without deleting its old content

Tags: python

I have a short question - I am using this code to save output to file - but at the moment it deletes the content in file and writes the new stuff in it - but I want to add the new content after the old and so on - how can I fix it?

```
with open('/home/pi/Desktop/Network/logs/logLocal.txt', "w") as f:
    f.write('\n' + all + '\n\n')
    for ip in range(1, 11):
            try:
              check_call(["ping", "-c", "1", "192.168.1.{}".format(ip)], stdout=open(devnull, "w"))
              f.write(to_words[ip])
            except CalledProcessError:
              pass
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Use the append file mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to append to the file, like so:

```
with open('/home/pi/Desktop/Network/logs/logLocal.txt', "a")
```

Notice the a standing for append. The w stood for write.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the file wrongly: you should use `open(file,"a")`. It opens `file` for *appending* while `"w"` opens it for *overwriting* or *creating*.

Answer (score 0):

choose`a`:add some words instead of `w`: write while deleting the old contents when calling `open`.